# Iframe check for the response after submitting the form in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I have been trying to embed Iframe in my react js project. The issue i am facing is that the source of Iframe is an external url which returns HTML form to me and then when i submit that form, they hit their own api to validate data and return HTML for success or failure.

So i need to access some specific classnames in order to know whether my response is successfull or not like

```
alert-success for success response
alert-failure for failed response
```

This is my code below for that

```
<iframe
              id="one"
              src={`https://xxxxxxxxx.com/Payments/xxxxxx?id=12232331&pais=pt&aseguradora=dg&nombre=CustomerName&apellidos=CustomerSurname&codPostal=CustomerPostalCode`}
              width="100%"
              height="300"
            ></iframe>
```

Now how can i access the classname in order to find response for that form, or is there any other workaround for this ?

tried `var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];`

but then I cannot access any classnames here or even after submitting the form (for alert-success or alert failure)

Comment: `the source of Iframe is an external url` - then you can't access it - unless the external url is also yours, then you can co-operatively communicate between parent and iframe using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) - but if you have no control over the "external url" content, then there is absolutely nothing you can do, there is no secret workaround, cross origin iframes are off limits for security

Comment: @Bravo so u mean i can only have access to conentWindow but not contentDocument ? and if i get access to contentDocument that would solve my case right ?

Comment: I'll re-type the first 5 words of my first comment slowly for you **then you can't access it** - the rest of that response applies in a very specific scenario, which probably does not apply to you, since you're still looking for a secret workaround